MySQL - query to get statistics across tenant databases
We have a multi-tenant application where:

Each tenant gets its own database (with for instance a table user)
A landlord table stores all tenants and its corresponding DB name

We need to get statistics across all tenants and before doing it the slow way with a PHP loop, I wanted to try doing it directly on the MySQL server.
From my research, and given my limited knowledge on prepared statements, I could come up with that code:
# landlord.tenants table has a db_name column
# each tenant DB has a users table
# We want to know how many users in total we have on the app 

SELECT
    GROUP_CONCAT(
            CONCAT(
                    '(SELECT count(id) FROM `',
                    db_name,
                    '`.`users`)' 
            ) 
            SEPARATOR ' + '
    ) as tmp
FROM
    landlord.tenants
INTO @sql;

SET @sql := CONCAT('SELECT ', @sql);

SELECT @sql;

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;

This works when you do not have many tenants. However, the result in our case is not correct because apparently GROUP_CONCAT has a limited maximum length which gets exceeded here.
How would you generalize such a request?
PS: most useful link has been SQL query to sum up count across multiple databases on same host from which I forged my own query.

the result in our case is not correct because apparently GROUP_CONCAT has a limited maximum length which gets exceeded here Adjust session @@group_concat_max_len system variable value.

Thanks a lot. Feel free to post an answer and I will mark it. In the mean time I have put it in an answer of mine.

Running the statement SET @@group_concat_max_len = 4294967295; before running the query extends the max length for GROUP_CONCAT and thus allows to get the proper result in our case.
NB: 4294967295 is the max accepted value on 32 bits systems according to the documentation, which is sufficient for our need.
Thanks a lot to https://stackoverflow.com/users/10138734/akina for his comment which lead to this answer.
